# Backup a user's OneDrive for Business account using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive, retention, o365security-compliance

Our company is implementing a process where we automatically backup specific users' Exchange mailbox and OneDrive contents during the offboarding process.
My idea was pretty simple: using the cmdlets for the Compliance center to retrieve both and schedule deletion after an x period of time.
The problem is the e-mail backup is working perfectly, but for some reason OneDrive is not.
I created a test account with some e-mails in its mailbox and a added some files to its OneDrive, but for some reason it's only saving the mailbox contents.
Here's my code:

```
# For running on Azure runbooks
$Creds = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "testcred"

Connect-IPPSSession -Credential $Creds

New-ComplianceSearch -Name "test-name" -ExchangeLocation "test.user@company.com" -AllowNotFoundExchangeLocationsEnabled $true -SharePointLocation "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/test_user_company_com/" | Start-ComplianceSearch
```

The search then pops up on https://compliance.microsoft.com/contentsearch and can be exported if necessary to access.
Problem is when I export it the contents of the OneDrive just simply don't show up even though in the compliance center it does seem to register the request for the site:

[image: compliancecenterprintscrn]

That's great, but then after extracting the contents to my PC no OneDrive contents come with:

[image: extractioncontents]

The Exchange folder contains the .pst file with mailbox contents, but no OneDrive files to be found.
Am I missing something here?
Edit: I should mention we use a 100% cloud Office 365 environment.
Edit2: Just as an additional proof, here's the content inside the OneDrive in the preview section of the Compliance's Content Search:

[image: searchcontents]

Answer (score 0):

I landed here when searching about another glitch on exporting Content Search OneDrive files.

Using Compliance Admin Center/Content Search I am able to export OneDrive files, but I have to explicitly set the user's URL (xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yyyy in my case).

(BTW, my problem is that the export has files with extensions such pdf_1E98101, msg_61c3b09 and so on... I am creating a question for this)

Comment: My solution to the issue was to just run two different compliance searches:  
`New-ComplianceSearch -Name $ExchangeComplianceSearchName -ExchangeLocation $Email -AllowNotFoundExchangeLocationsEnabled $True | Start-ComplianceSearch
New-ComplianceSearch -Name $OneDriveComplianceSearchName -SharePointLocation $UserPersonalOneDriveUrl | Start-ComplianceSearch`. Only issue is it won't bundle in the same export, but for my case that was fine